# How would i add this to a repeater?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql, repeater, asp.net-controls

Morning,

I am writing a simple quiz app. I am getting my questions and answers from the my MS SQL DB. How would i go about getting this and putting it into say a repeater control, so i can display 6 questions, with their answers.

Or... do you know of a better way to do this?

```
 var questions = dc.Questions.ToList().OrderBy(q => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(6);

        foreach (var q in questions)
        {
            litQuestion.Text = q.question1;
            int qId = q.id;

            var ans = dc.Answers.Where(a => a.questionId == qId).ToList();

            litAnswer1.Text = ans[0].answer1.ToString();
            litAnswer2.Text = ans[1].answer1.ToString();
            litAnswer3.Text = ans[2].answer1.ToString();
        }
```

dc is my datacontext.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides the other answers, this is a really simple way to do it:

Assuming your **Question** object contains a collection of available answers called **Answers**

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" DataSourceID="ods">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# Eval("QuestionText") %>
        <br />
        <asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" DataSource='<%# Eval("Answers") %>' DataTextField="AnswerText" DataValueField="ID">
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Which produces something like:

[image]

### Edit 1

The ods DataSource:

```
    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ods" runat="server" 
        SelectMethod="GetQuestions" 
        TypeName="WebApplication1.Questions.QuestionsContext">
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>

    public IEnumerable<Question> GetQuestions()
    {
        // return your questions
    }

public class Question
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string QuestionText { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
    public bool MultipleAnswers { get; set; }
    public bool IsCorrect { get; set; }

    public Question()
    {
        this.Answers = Enumerable.Empty<Answer>();
    }
}
public class Answer
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public Question Question { get; set; }
    public bool IsCorrect { get; set; }
    public string AnswerText { get; set; }
    public bool WasSelected { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: how are you getting these? I can see your connecting to the ods as a datasource?

Comment: @Jupaol: Perfect answer. Helped me after 2 years ! Just an observation: Class Question contains Answers and Answer Class contains Question. Circular reference or I am missing something !

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started:

Markup:

```
<asp:repeater ID="repeater" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="repeater_OnItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:Label id="lblQuestion" runat="server" />
           <asp:Label id="lblAnswer" runat="server" />                 
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:repeater>
```

Code behind:

```
public void repeater_OnItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item) || (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem))
    {
        Label lblQuestion = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblQuestion");
        Label lblAnswer = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblAnswer");

        //Your logic for getting the questions and answers per iteration
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don´t know the number of answers per question, you could use a nested repeater

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="questionsRep" OnItemDataBound="QuestionsRep_ItemDataBound">

        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("question1") %>'></asp:Label>
            <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("id") %>'></asp:Label>

            <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="answersRep">

                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("answer1") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>

            </asp:Repeater>

        </ItemTemplate>

    </asp:Repeater>
```

In the Databound-Event of the repeater, bind the answers

```
protected void QuestionsRep_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item) || (e.Item.ItemType ==    
    ListItemType.AlternatingItem))
    {
        Question q = (Question)e.Item.DataItem;
        var answers = dc.Answers.Where(a => a.questionId == q.id).ToList();
        Repeater answersRep = (Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("answersRep");
        answersRep.DataSource = answers;
        answersRep.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: 'abc_quiz.Question' does not contain a definition for 'Answers' and no extension method 'Answers' accepting a first argument of type 'abc_quiz.Question' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) Is the error i am getting? Any ideas?

Comment: your question object does not contain a property answers, I think. You have to get them again from dc (see my edit)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of binding in DataBound event of repeater, you can also use server side tags (if you are just displaying questions and answers):

aspx:

```
        <asp:Repeater ID="quizRepeater" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="fullWidthDiv">
            <span class="rightAlignedForQuestion">
                <asp:Label ID="questionNumberLabel" runat="server">
        Question
        <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"QuestionNumber") %>:
                </asp:Label>
            </span><span class="leftAlignedForQuestion">
                <label>
                    <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Question") %>
                </label>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="fullWidthDiv">
            <span class="leftAlignedForOptions">
            Correct Answer: 
                <asp:Label CssClass="boldFont" id="correctAnswerLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Answer") %>'>
                </asp:Label>
            </span>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

while QuestionNumber, Question and Answers will be properties/columns of you binding list/DataTable.